# Multi Routes handling - Getting exception while using own requesthandler

Tags: java, playframework

I am using play 2.5.3 and having 2 routes files sitting under subproject. Idea is to use the domain related route file.
Code Structure:

```
root
- modules
  - core
  - admin
    - admin.routes
  - web
    - web.routes
```

My RequestHandler looks like this--

```
public class MyRequestHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {    
    @Inject
    public MyRequestHandler(web.Routes webRoutes, admin.Routes adminRoutes) {
        this.webRoutes = webRoutes;
        this.adminRoutes = adminRoutes;
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerForRequest handlerForRequest(Http.RequestHeader request) {
        String subDomain = getSubDomain(request);
        if("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(subDomain)){
            Handler handler = adminRoutes.asJava().route(request).get();
            return new HandlerForRequest(request,handler);
        }else{
            Handler handler = webRoutes.asJava().route(request).get();
            return new HandlerForRequest(request,handler);
        }
    }

}
```

Getting Following exception -

```
2016-05-10 13:02:29,956 - [ERROR] - p.c.s.n.PlayRequestHandler - Exception caught in Netty
scala.MatchError: Right((play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3@50a3f51b,play.api.DefaultApplication@2072c28f)) (of class scala.util.Right)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.handle(PlayRequestHandler.scala:93)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.channelRead(PlayRequestHandler.scala:163)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:129)
        at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:96)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:278)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:292)
2016-05-10 13:02:34,020 - [ERROR] - p.c.s.n.PlayRequestHandler - Exception caught in Netty
```

Please help us in this regard. Or let us know is there any other way.

Comment: We have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I was able to solve it. Answer given by Miph is similar to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Need to create Javacompatible RequestHandler. I changed my code as below. No 404 anymore.

```
public class MyRequestHandler implements HttpRequestHandler { 
private play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler adminRequestHandler;
private play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler webRequestHandler;

@Inject
public MyRequestHandler(web.Routes webRoutes, HttpErrorHandler httpErrorHandler,admin.Routes adminRoutes,
                        HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpFilters httpFilters,
                        JavaHandlerComponents components) {
    adminRequestHandler = new JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler(adminRoutes,httpErrorHandler
            ,configuration, httpFilters,components);
    webRequestHandler = new JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler(webRoutes,httpErrorHandler
            ,configuration, httpFilters,components);
}

 @Override
public HandlerForRequest handlerForRequest(Http.RequestHeader request) {
    Logger.info("Request ---> ["+ request.method()+"] "+request.host() + request.uri() );
    if("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(getSubDomain(request))){
        Tuple2<RequestHeader, Handler> result = adminRequestHandler.handlerForRequest(request._underlyingHeader());
        return new HandlerForRequest(new RequestHeaderImpl(result._1()), result._2());
    }else {
        Tuple2<RequestHeader, Handler> result = webRequestHandler.handlerForRequest(request._underlyingHeader());
        return new HandlerForRequest(new RequestHeaderImpl(result._1()), result._2());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have Java controllers, you either need to implement it in Scala using play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler, or in Java using play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler. The general assumption is that Java users will use the play.http.* classes and Scala users will use play.api.http.* ones.
2. Since the Handler is a play.api.mvc.Handler (Scala), the routing actually only works when routing to Scala controllers. If you try to route to a Java controller then you will get the error I described above.
   So, if the Handler you get back is a JavaHandler, you need to call handler.withComponents(components), where components is an injected JavaHandlerComponents. That will return an instance of EssentialAction that the Play Netty server will be able to deal with.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.4/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/HttpRequestHandler.scala#L206 (override def routeRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Based on `Andrii Kliui` advice I came to this solution:

```
import play.api.mvc.Handler;
import play.core.j.JavaHandler;
import play.core.j.JavaHandlerComponents;
import play.http.HandlerForRequest;
import play.http.HttpRequestHandler;
import play.mvc.Http;
import router.Routes;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyCustomHttpRequestHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

    private final Routes myRoutes;
    private final JavaHandlerComponents components;

    @Inject
    public MyCustomHttpRequestHandler(router.Routes myRoutes, JavaHandlerComponents components) {
        this.myRoutes = myRoutes;
        this.components = components;
    }


    @Override
    public HandlerForRequest handlerForRequest(Http.RequestHeader request) {
        JavaHandler handler = (JavaHandler) myRoutes.asJava().route(request).get();
        Handler newHandler = handler.withComponents(components);

        return new HandlerForRequest(request, newHandler);
    }
}
```

I noticed that in case above there will be some problems with `DefaultHttpErrorHandler` (for example 404 page will not work). To fix this in `handlerForRequest` I need to check:

```
Optional<Handler> route = myRoutes.asJava().route(request);
if (route.isPresent()) {
    JavaHandler handler = (JavaHandler) route.get();
    Handler newHandler = handler.withComponents(components);
    return new HandlerForRequest(request, newHandler);
} else {
    // this is the default behaviour from play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler
    Tuple2<RequestHeader, Handler> result = underlying.handlerForRequest(request._underlyingHeader());
    return new HandlerForRequest(new RequestHeaderImpl(result._1()), result._2());
}
```